# Accessing JSON by few last character of KEY

Tags: javascript, json

```
var a = {
    state: "",
    city: "",
}

var b = {
    resident_state: "US",
    resident_city: "NY",
}
```

I want to write function so that i can:

If the last 5 character of Key identifier of `b` JSON object is 'state' then append it to `a` JSON object state identifier.

Else if last 4 char of Key identifier is matching 'city' then append it to `a` JSON object state identifier.

**Output:**

```
a = {
    state: "US",
    city: "NY",
}
```

Comment: @Bravo No, I want to check last few char

Comment: `a[key.split('_')[1]]`…?

Comment: Well, what have you tried and where are you stuck? It's really more words to describe it in English than to actually code it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop through the keys of `b` and act accordingly

```js
var a = {
  state: "",
  city: "",
}

var b = {
  resident_state: "US",
  resident_city: "NY",
}

Object.keys(b).forEach(key => {
  if (key.endsWith('state')) {
    a.state = b[key]
  } else if (key.endsWith('city')) {
    a.city = b[key]
  }
})

console.log(a);
```